# Dynamically generating bitheader

Tags: expl3, bytefield

I'm trying to dynamically generate a bit header according to what fields
are present in a bytefield. I am using LaTeX3 to do so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \tl_head
\tl_new:N \tl_body
\int_new:N \int_bits
\int_new:N \int_diff

\newcommand\field[2]{
  \int_set:Nn \int_diff \int_bits
  \int_sub:Nn \int_diff { #1 - 1 }
  \tl_gput_left:Nx \tl_head
     {\the\int_diff \int_compare:nNnTF {#1}={1} {} {,\the\int_bits}
       \int_compare:nNnTF {\the\int_bits}={31} {} {,}
     }
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \tl_body {\bitbox{#1}{#2}}
  \int_sub:Nn \int_diff { 1 }
  \int_set:Nn \int_bits \int_diff
}

\NewEnviron{register}[1]{
  \int_set:Nn \int_bits {31}
  \tl_set:Nn \tl_head {}
  \tl_set:Nn \tl_body {}
  \BODY
  \begin{bytefield}{32}
%    \bitheader{tl_use:N \tl_head} \\
    \begin{rightwordgroup}{#1}
      \tl_use:N \tl_body
    \end{rightwordgroup}\\
  \end{bytefield}\\
  \tl_use:N \tl_head
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{register}{example}
\field{8}{c} \field{8}{b} \field{16}{a}
\end{register}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

However, when I uncomment the line `\bitheader{tl_use:N \tl_head} \\`

I get the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   t
l.45 \end{register}
                   
?
```

I assume this issue has something to do with macro expansion, but liberal use of `\expandafter` hasn't helped either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were missing a `\` in `tl_use:N`, and `\bitheader` expects its argument fully expanded, so you have to expand it before passing it on.  Change `\bitheader{tl_use:N \tl_head}` to `\exp_args:NV \bitheader \tl_head` and your code will work.  However I made a few more (mostly cosmetic) changes to make your code obey `expl3` guidelines (take a look at “The expl3 language and LaTeX3 programming” ([`expl3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf)—`texdoc expl3`), section **3 The naming scheme**).

- Variables should be named `\<scope>_<module>_<description>_<type>`, whereas yours were `\<type>_<description>`.  A variable like `\tl_head` should be named (supposing it's global, since you use global assignments, and supposing the module name is `junius`) `\g_junius_head_tl`.  Same for integers: `\int_bits` → `\l_junius_bits_int`.
- Avoid primitives in `expl3` code, and avoid and mixing styles. `\the \l_junius_bits_int` is better written as `\int_use:N \l_junius_bits_int`.
- You can omit conditional branches: `\int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {#2} { } { <stuff> }` doesn't need the `T` branch and can be written more concisely as `\int_compare:nNnF {#1} = {#2} { <stuff> }`.
- Finally, starting from TeXLive 2019, `xparse` has a `b`-type argument for environments, which grab the environment body, so you can use that instead of `environ`.

Add those changes up, and here's your code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \g_junius_head_tl
\tl_new:N \g_junius_body_tl
\int_new:N \l_junius_bits_int
\int_new:N \l_junius_diff_int

\NewDocumentCommand \field { m m }
  {
    \int_set_eq:NN \l_junius_diff_int \l_junius_bits_int
    \int_sub:Nn \l_junius_diff_int { #1 - 1 }
    \tl_gput_left:Nx \g_junius_head_tl
      {
        \int_use:N \l_junius_diff_int
        \int_compare:nNnF {#1} = { 1 } { , \int_use:N \l_junius_bits_int }
        \int_compare:nNnF { \l_junius_bits_int } = {31} { , }
      }
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_junius_body_tl { \bitbox {#1} {#2} }
    \int_sub:Nn \l_junius_diff_int { 1 }
    \int_set:Nn \l_junius_bits_int \l_junius_diff_int
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { register } { m b }
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_junius_bits_int { 31 }
    \tl_gclear:N \g_junius_head_tl
    \tl_gclear:N \g_junius_body_tl
    #2 % environment body
    \begin{bytefield}{32}
      \exp_args:NV \bitheader \g_junius_head_tl \\
      \begin{rightwordgroup}{#1}
        \tl_use:N \g_junius_body_tl
      \end{rightwordgroup}\\
    \end{bytefield}\\
    \tl_use:N \g_junius_head_tl
  }
  { }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{register}{example}
\field{8}{c} \field{8}{b} \field{16}{a}
\end{register}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: This is great, thank you. My last question is, how would I pass optional arguments to `\bitheader` in your example. Like `\bitheader[endianness=big]`?

Comment: @junius You can add an optional argument to the environment. Something like: `\NewDocumentEnvironment { register } { m O{} b }
  {
    \int_set:Nn \l_junius_bits_int { 31 }
    \tl_gclear:N \g_junius_head_tl
    \tl_gclear:N \g_junius_body_tl
    #3 % environment body
    \begin{bytefield}{32}
      \use:x { \exp_not:N \bitheader [ { \exp_not:n {#2} } ] \exp_not:V \g_junius_head_tl } \\
      \begin{rightwordgroup}{#1}
        \tl_use:N \g_junius_body_tl
      \end{rightwordgroup}\\
    \end{bytefield}\\
    \tl_use:N \g_junius_head_tl
  }
  { }`.